# Center alignment of iOS Charts

Tags: ios, ios-charts

I am using iosCharts Framework for desiging Line and Bar charts in iOS application.

I have a requirment of displaying the charts from Center instead of left.

Is it possible in iOSCharts. If Yes can any one provide me the solution.

I am using below code to display the Line Chart.

```
var set = new LineChartDataSet(values.ToArray(), "Precipitation");
            set.Mode = LineChartMode.Linear;
            set.CubicIntensity = (float)0.2;
            set.DrawCirclesEnabled = false;
            set.LineWidth = (float)1.8;
            set.CircleRadius = (float)4.0;
            set.SetCircleColor(UIColor.FromRGBA(41, 41, 255, 255));
            set.SetColor(UIColor.FromRGBA(41, 41, 255, 255));
            set.FillColor = UIColor.FromRGBA(41, 41, 255, 255);
            set.FillAlpha = (float)1.0;
            set.DrawHorizontalHighlightIndicatorEnabled = false;
            set.LineCapType = CGLineCap.Butt;
            set.DrawValuesEnabled = false;
            dataSets.AddDataSet(set);
            chartView.Data = dataSets;
```

Comment: Please post a snippet of the code used to build the Chart.

Comment: @Len_X I have added the snippet of the code for building line chart.

Comment: Did you found anything? if not try adding some values to chart minimumX value https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67150237/how-to-make-horizontal-padding-in-ios-danielgindi-charts